# How to change comment syntax in Geany

Tags: geany

In Geany, editing PHP scripts, when you select lines and press control-e, the selected lines are commented by being wrapped in "/* ... */".  Is there a way to change this behaviour so that it instead puts a "//" in front of each line?

All the other IDEs that I've used make use of "//" (Eclipse, Netbeans, Textmate, etc).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Settings like comment characters are controlled by [filetype definition files](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/#filetype-definition-files). Assuming your scripts end in `.php`, you should find the default system-wide filetype definition file `filetypes.php`, and copy it to your `filedefs` directory in your user configuration directory. Then you can modify it as necessary.

This is all explained in detail in the manual (link above).